# Link straight into a specific tab-pane from another page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the following code to separate content on a website http://www.bootply.com/74926 and it is working fine.

However, if I wanted to link straight to a specific tab from **another** page how can I go about doing this?

Using the regular way with an ID in the url doesn't seem to work - e.g. mypage.html#a

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, did it work? If yes could you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 6):

Although I do not have the chance to try it, I think you can do it via javascript.

When you are comming from another page to ex. `mypage#abc`, `#abc` can be retrieved by `window.location.hash`. So, a simple solution could be this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // get the tab from url
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    // if a hash is present (when you come to this page)
    if (hash !='') {
        // show the tab
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

Just make sure that the tabs you need to link (from other pages) have ids same as your hashes

Answer (score 0):

The Advantage with this code is that you can navigate to those tabs from other sites as well not only within the same page.

```
$('#tab1 a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
})
```

You can see it working in my JSFiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/Anokrize/nP2Zk/317/