# How to make an <a> link go to a specific tab-pane (not just page section) in another page

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

My question is very similar to [this post here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687328/getting-a-link-to-go-to-a-specific-section-on-another-page)
But my issue is distinct from this as I am trying to:

- Make a link to a ***specific bootstrap tab-pane*** not just on another page at a specific location.

I tried the solution they suggested:

```
// ** Page One **
// In Nav
// Nav item 
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#work"> 
      <span>Portfolio Projects</span> 
      <i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i>
  </a>
  <ul>
       <li><a href="portfolio-details.html#proj1">Proj 1</a></li>
       // All links currently go to this default tab
       // So this one does work

                 
       <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="portfolio-details.html#proj2">Proj 2</a></li>
       // I have tried it this way as they used in that post ^ 
       // data-toggle="tab" is what Bootstrap uses to change the tabs
       // But while this takes to the correct page, it navigates to the DEFAULT tab not proj2 tab
                  
       <li><a href="portfolio-details.html#proj3"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#proj3">Proj 3</a></a></li>
       // Above I tried some other different ways to see if I could get to port-dets.html first, 
       // then navigate to the respective tab by id using data-toggle="tab" 
       // But this also does not work.
   </ul>
</li>
```

Is there a way I can achieve navigating to a specific tab in another page?

Comment: I did just find this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906968/link-straight-into-a-specific-tab-pane-from-another-page
but it doesn't have an answer that solves my issue.